# any way to do feature selection for dataframe by computing its mutual information or information gain in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, feature-extraction

I am interested in computing mutual information entropy for all rows of dataframe (a.k.a, features) then do feature selection by looking up its MI value. In my dataset, rows are raw feature set, columns are different groups. I understand the concept of pairwise mutual information (PMI) in NLP but not quite sure MI in R. Essentially I want to make feature selection by computing its mutual information entropy. How can I do that in R? any efficient way to make this happen? Or is there any R package can do this for feature selection? Any thought would be appreciated.

**reproducible data**:

here is the reproducible data that can be used:

```
> dput(HTA20_filt_corr[1:20, 1:5])
structure(c(6.06221469449721, 3.79648446367096, 4.44302662142323, 
5.83652223195279, 2.68934375273141, 2.74561888109989, 3.79468365910661, 
2.84818282222582, 2.14058977019523, 2.6928480064245, 2.35292391447048, 
2.48476830655452, 6.53876010917445, 4.65751152599579, 3.04781583130435, 
5.77123333840058, 3.12373340327186, 2.19534644753427, 2.97565909758917, 
3.32457362519432, 5.8755020052495, 3.45024474095539, 4.3934877055859, 
5.89836406552412, 2.55675627493564, 2.70765553292035, 4.29971184424969, 
2.48325694938049, 2.26880029802564, 3.03461160119094, 2.3853610213164, 
2.28880889278209, 7.38935014141236, 5.99396449205588, 2.81020023855867, 
6.15414625452898, 2.71038534186171, 2.23803889487068, 2.83352503485538, 
3.40195667040699, 6.12613148162098, 3.62841140410044, 4.6237834519809, 
6.01979203584278, 2.61341541015611, 2.80774129091983, 3.81085169542991, 
3.2386968734862, 2.3315210232915, 2.75618624035735, 2.36292219228603, 
2.31409329648109, 6.89661896623484, 4.94260091412701, 3.30560274327296, 
5.4547259473827, 2.41056409104863, 2.26899775961818, 2.6699701841279, 
3.01459760807053, 6.1345548976595, 3.51232455992681, 4.66743523288194, 
5.98400432133011, 2.69430042092269, 2.8653583834812, 3.81895258294878, 
2.72080210986981, 2.33064119419619, 2.77388400895015, 2.46939314182722, 
2.28927162732448, 6.93808821971072, 5.63306489420911, 2.75877942216047, 
5.82872398278859, 2.92710196023309, 2.34137181372226, 2.52271243341233, 
2.96285787017003, 6.28953417729806, 3.56819306931016, 4.97483476597509, 
6.1149144301085, 2.73207812554522, 3.00137677271996, 4.03594900960396, 
2.58058159047299, 2.24052626899434, 3.2286586324064, 2.30413560438815, 
2.38147147362554, 6.58149585137493, 4.16189923349488, 2.36086328728537, 
5.57065453220316, 2.57313948725185, 2.36046878474564, 2.54370710157379, 
2.97488700289993), .Dim = c(20L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("1_at", 
"10_at", "100009613_at", "100009676_at", "10003_at", "100033411_at", 
"100033414_at", "100033418_at", "100033422_at", "100033423_at", 
"100033424_at", "100033425_at", "100033426_at", "100033431_at", 
"100033432_at", "100033434_at", "100033436_at", "100033437_at", 
"100033438_at", "100033439_at"), c("Tarca_001_P1A01", "Tarca_004_P1A04", 
"Tarca_005_P1A05", "Tarca_007_P1A07", "Tarca_008_P1A08")))
```

**my trivial attempt**:

```
require(infotheo)
apply(HTA20_filt_corr,1, mutinformation)
```

but I think this is not a proper way of computing mutual information and make feature selection based on that. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? Thanks

**desired output**:

basically, in my expected output, original dataframe should be shrinked /filtered the features by looking up its mutual information entropy table. How can I get this done in R? any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure what you intend. Mutual information is a function of two arguments (two features, hence the name "mutual"), so for each feature you will have as many numbers as there are features in your data set. How are you going filter on that?

Comment: @January thanks for heads up. In my actual dataset, I have 32830 rows and 735 columns. Do you think is that possible to compute mutual information for row against columns and set up threshold to filter the rows? Can we also compute MI value row wise recursively? Thanks a lot

Comment: "row against columns"  - I think that this does not make any sense. You can ask how much information gene X provides about gene Y and vice versa (this is MI). You cannot ask "how much gene X provides information about sample Z". This is like asking "what is the correlation coefficient between gene X and sample Z".

Comment: If by "filtering genes" you mean "filtering genes using MI", I have no idea. This is akin to filtering genes using correlation coefficient. What is your goal in that? If, however, you mean how to filter genes in general, there are a lot of options; but that is another question better suited to BioStars than stackoverflow.

Comment: I have been analysing transcriptomic data for past ten years and, as I mentioned, I have no idea how you could do that. You can use MI for lots of things, for example to find clusters of co-dependent genes or to find which genes are not MI with your gene of interest, you can try to figure out how MI changes between conditions, but filtering is not one of them.

Comment: @January Thanks a lot for your help. I am curious how can retrieve which genes are not MI with gene of interest (for instance, top 100 highly correlated or top-ranked genes)? Any idea?

Comment: given gene of interest x and a matrix of discretized gene expression values Y (where genes are in columns), try to run `apply(Y, 2, function(y) mutinformation(Y[,x], y))`. This should return a vector which you can order. Note, however, that with the few samples you were showing, MI discretization will not allow for a high resolution of MI, and consequently you will have hundreds of genes with identical MI's.

Comment: @January Do you think what is the proper way to find the gene of interest (use feature importance)? Any extended solution on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196505/discussion-between-january-and-jerry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutual information is a bit like a correlation: you need at least two vectors for that. With your data, you can calculate for example the mutual information between 100009613_at and 10003_at. Or all features against all features. But first, you need to transform your data: mutual information needs to be discretized first.

```
mtx <- data.matrix(HTA20_filt_corr)
mtx <- t(mtx) # features in columns
mtxd <- discretize(mtx, nbins=3)

mutinformation(mtxd[,"100009613_at"], mtxd[,"10003_at"])
# [1] 0.7776613

# or, each against each
eae <- mutinformation(mtxd)
```

Take a look at `mtxd`. It is a square matrix. So, how did you want to use it for filtering the features?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure what you mean. Why would you want to make a nested loop and what does it have to do with recursion? Which MI's would you like to calculate? Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I think `[[float(y) for y in x] for x in l]` something like this, and use it for computing mutual information. Could you update your solution? thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you want to use this construct if you can do it directly with one call? `mutinformation(mtxd)` calculates each against each and returns a square matrix.